# red dot on subdomain for licensed imageresizer

Tags: imageresizer

I use imagerizer on my website which works very well. I purchased a license for my domain like fotoapparatuur.nl and installed it in the webconfig assuming this would work on all subdomains as described on the licensing page. However I actually use it on www.fotoapparatuur.nl and get red dots on my pictures.

The resizer.debug states:
resizer configuration(Error):   No license found for domain www.fotoapparatuur.nl - features installed: R4Performance or R4BlobProviders AND R4Performance or R4DiskCache AND R4Creative or R4Watermark

List of installed domain licenses:
fotoapparatuur.nl => R4Performance

How do I get imageresizer to work on subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Creative edition, but only bought a Performance license. Uninstall the Waterkmark plugin (Creative edition) and licensing system will be happy.